# How to fix pipenv error: Could not find a version that matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pipfile, pipenv-install

I have the following pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "${PYPI_ENDPOINT}"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
flask-shell-ipython = "==0.4.*" 
ipython = "==7.4.*"

[packages]
boto3 = "==1.9.*"
statsd = "==3.2.1"
gunicorn = ">=19.7.0,<20.0.0"
python-dotenv = "==0.8.2"
Flask = "==1.0.2"
pyflogger = "==0.1.*"
mongoengine = "==0.17.*"
sagemaker = "==1.18.*"
databricks-connect = "==5.2.*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.5.3"
```

Everything was ok, but once I changed `databricks-connect` version to `"==5.5.*"` I cannot built a project locally and in jenkins, because of the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches flask-shell-ipython==0.4.*  (from -r /tmp/pipenv0ut3ryizrequirements/pipenv-igwd4wtq-constraints.txt (line 2))
```

I decided to not specify the concrete version of this lib and changed the pipfile to

```
[dev-packages]
flask-shell-ipython = "*"
```

but still have the exception:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches flask-shell-ipython
```

That is my .yml file

```
    command_list:
      - name: Generate a template
        command: ./etc/build_config_files.sh ./templates ~
      - name: virtual env
        command: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv -p /home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python .jarvis
      - name: run
        command: . ./.jarvis/bin/activate && ./.jarvis/bin/pip install pipenv && ./.funnel_prediction_jarvis/bin/pipenv install && ./.jarvis/bin/pipenv run python -u script/fetch_kw_lp_mapping.py
      - name: remove databricks connect config file
        command: rm -f ~/.databricks-connect
```

What is the way to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to clear the cache? https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/diagnose/#your-dependencies-could-not-be-resolved

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @KeepLearning, I had to tweak mine.

I had to

1. remove `Pipefile.lock`
2. run `pipenv --rm` (to remove the pipenv shell I was in)
3. run `pip install pipenv --upgrade`
4. run `pipenv install`

Hope that helps if you are still running into issues. You could possibly try looking into your python interpreter as well and seeing how your path is set up if you installed via homebrew. You may need to run `brew update && brew upgrade` and then `brew reinstall python`

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your pipenv maybe
`pip install pipenv --upgrade`